# Switch between two functions on each click in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here it is a html page where it is called a method every time `ng-click` is triggered:

```
<div ng-repeat="page in $ctrl.users">
    <main-component page="$ctrl.pageNames[page]"
                    ng-click="$ctrl.updateLegendChart($ctrl.pageNames[page])"
                    users= "$ctrl.users">
    </main-component>
</div>
```

`ng-click` calls `updateLegendChart` which is a method inside a controller looking like this:

```
updateLegendChart(pageNames){

    this.chartStuff.chart.unload(pageNames);
}
```

Until now it works as expected, `unload()` removes a line from the chart.

What I want to do is to add it back when I click again there. To behave as a light switch.

Basically, it should be added the `load()` method there but I didn't manage to create the switch functionality.

I tried like this without succes:

```
updateLegendChart(pageNames){

    let aswitch = true;
    if(aswitch){
        this.chartStuff.chart.unload(pageNames);
        aswitch = false;
        return;
    }
    if(!aswitch){   
        this.chartStuff.chart.load(RandomCtrl.chartStuff.allCols[0]);
        aswitch = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put `let aswitch = true;` outside of the `updateLegendChart` method, since you are initializing it  with `true` value everytime you are calling this method.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash Tried to define it outside the function scope which is inside a controller and I have this error: > [js] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

Comment: Is it TypeScript? Asking you, since you've tagged post with `javascript` tag..

Comment: nope, it's javascript, angularJS 1.6

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Comment: yes, doesn't work...

Comment: What actually is not working? Does it throw any errors? Can you debug and see what value `this.aswitch` has?

Comment: actually it works, I didn't test it as it should. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, you have to declare `aswitch` outside of `updateLegendChart` method, since you don't want to initialize it each time, you are calling it. Make it global for your controller class like:

```
class DemandCtrl {
    constructor() {
        this.aswitch = true;
    }

    updateLegendChart(pageNames) {
        if (this.aswitch) {
            this.chartStuff.chart.unload(pageNames);
        } else {
            this.chartStuff.chart.load(RandomCtrl.chartStuff.allCols[0]);
        }
        this.aswitch = !this.aswitch;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ES2015:
inside constructor:

```
class DemandCtrl {
    constructor(ChartDataService) {
        ...
        this.aswitch = true;
    }
....
```

Comment: Tried to define it outside the function scope which is inside a controller and I have this error: > [js] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

Comment: Try this, `$scope.aswitch` instead of just using `let aswitch`

Comment: This code your code is not Js ES5, it looks like JS ES2015

Comment: it is the latest ecmascript but it is angularJS 1.6. tried with `$scope.aswitch`, got this error: ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Comment: now it says that  aswitch is not defined.  I added it as you say, tried it and failed, tried again with adding `this.` before it inside `updateLegendChart`

Comment: I tried simple version of your code and it's working, investigate it more, the problem is not with the solution of setting the variable like this: `this.aswitch`. something else maybe the cause of the error.